# access button title gives wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my storyboard, my button attribute is like this:

[image]

You see the value "3" under title.

I try to access this value programmatically in IBAction by:

```
IBAction func bugTypeSelected(sender: UIButton) {
     print("title = \(sender.titleLabel?.text)")
}
```

The print out value however is `title = Optional("Button")` , why it is not `Option("3")`?

Comment: Don't use `titleLabel.text` to get a button's title. Use `title(for:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to instead use

```
if let title = sender.title(for: .normal) {
   print("title = \(title)")
}
```

Comment: You misread the question. The question is asking with the result is `Optional("Button")` instead of `Optional("3")`. The question is not about the "Optional" part but about the actual button title being "Button" instead of "3".

Comment: the question title is
"access button title gives wrong value"
so I provided the way to obtain correct value :)

Comment: Yes, you show the use of `title(for:)` but the text of your question implies the issue is all about the unwrapping. The unwrapping has nothing to do with the question. Focus your question on the proper use of `title(for:)` vs. `titleLabel.text`.